# ¿Cómo hacer split a un arreglo json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, array, split

Quiero dividir la respuesta de un servicio de la siguiente manera, pero el navegador me dice que:

> resp.split is not a function.

Que puedo hacer? el servidor me regresa 8 estados separados por comas los cuales quiero hacer pedacitos y meterlos en sus respectivas variables para luego setear un `local storage`

Quedaria algo como esto:
  `("true","false", "true","true","false", "true","true","false")`

Esta es mi **función**:

```
//FUNCION PARA CONSULTAR LA CONFIGURACION DE NOTIFICACIONES
function consulta_configuracion($http, vg, $scope, usuario) {

    $http({
        url: vg,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            usuario: usuario

        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'dataType': 'json'
        }
    })
    .success(function (response) {

        var resp = response;
        console.log(resp);        


        var x = resp.split(",");

                var x1 = x[0];
                var x2 = x[1];
                var x3 = x[2];
                var x4 = x[3];
                var x5=  x[4];
                var x6 = x[5];
                var x7 = x[6];
                var x8 = x[7];


                localStorage.setItem("n1", x1);
                localStorage.setItem("n2", x2);
                localStorage.setItem("n3", x3);
                localStorage.setItem("n4", x4);
                localStorage.setItem("n5", x5);
                localStorage.setItem("n6", x6);
                localStorage.setItem("n7", x7);
                localStorage.setItem("n8", x8);

                console.log(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8);



                                                                                                                                     // var x = response.split(",");
                                                                                                                                            //  var x = resp.split(",");
                                                                                                                                           // var x1 = x[0];
                                                                                                                                            //  var x2 = x[1];
                                                                                                                                            // var x3 = x[2];
                                                                                                                                            // var x4 = x[3];
                                                                                                                                            // var x5 = x[4];
                                                                                                                                            // var x6 = x[5];
                                                                                                                                            // var x7 = x[6];
                                                                                                                                            // var x8 = x[7];
                                                                                                                                            // console.log(x1);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // alert("Error: " + error);
    });

}
```

Comment: resp parece ser que no es un string, debe ser un tipo objeto, deberias hacer typeof(resp) a ver que te retorna, podrias agregar la  respuesta para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Exctamente `"true","false", "true","true","false", "true","true","false"` como llega?. Si es un string si deberia dejar hace `split'. @JackNavaRow tiene razon en lo que dice

Comment: lo puse asi     var x = typeof(resp).split(",");  y me regreso el mismo error 
resp.split is not a function

Comment: tienes que poner console.log(typeof resp);

Comment: Ya brothers  .  ..  me devolvio object como respuesta el console.log(typeof resp);

Comment: por ser object no puedes hacer un split , por lo tanto puedes acceder con res[0] directamente

Comment: Que imprime `console.log(resp)`?

Comment: la respuesta te lo dice, no preste atencion ` "true","false",` fijate que cierra comilla y luego debe abrir , te devuelve un arreglo pero lo vez como string porque al hacer el `console.log(res`) lo visualizas de esa forma porque javascript automaticamente hace`res.toString()`

Comment: hola brothers trate de acceder de la siguiente forma   

      var x1 = resp[0];
        var x2 = resp[1];
        console.log(x1);
        console.log(x2);

me da undefined para x1 y x2

Comment: intenta acceder de esta forma `res["0"]`

Comment: console.log(resp);   imprime

 valores: (8) ["True", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False"]

el alert(resp);   imprime [ object  object ]  nadamas

Comment: res["0"];  me da undefined @jackNavaRow

Comment: por favor cambia tu respuesta del back , colocalo en una variable para que sea mas facil.

Comment: me podrias enseñar un ejemplo no veo ningun bak ahah

Comment: puedes utilizar un `JSON.parse` para transformar tu objeto a un array y de ahí formar lo que quieres...

Comment: Hola Cig     JSON.parse(resp);  me dice que unexpecten token o in Json at position 1  
 agradesco tus comentarios

Comment: ¿Cuál es el JSON que estás recibiendo?

Answer (score 1):

Hola porque no haces esto:

```
var myJson = JSON.stringify(resp);
console.log(myJson);
```

y me muestras que te devuelve para poder ayudarte :)

Comment: les agradesco mucho su ayuda .. ya pude resoverlo accedi directamente al valor .. ya que estaba accediendo de manera erronea 

quedo de la siguiente manera la funcion de respuesta 

gracias a todos .. saludos!

.success(function (response) {

        var resp = response;
        console.log(resp);

        var x1 = response.valores[0];
        console.log(x1);
        localStorage.setItem("noti1", x1);
        var x2 = response.valores[1];
        console.log(x2);
        localStorage.setItem("noti2", x2);
        var x3 = response.valores[2];